# Django How can i split string using template tag

Tags: python, django

Hello I want to know that how can I split string of dictionary values

This is my crawler which is returns dictionary data looks like

```
data = {
    {0:'http://..., product name, product price'},
    {1:'http://...2, product name2, product price2'},
    {N:'http://...2, product name2, product price n'}
}
```

I want to split these data by comma 
 like,

```
for value in data.values():
     href, product_name, product_price = str(value).split(",")
```

in Django

This is my crawler.py

```
import requests
from urllib import parse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def spider(item_name):
    url_item_name = parse.quote(item_name.encode('euc-kr'))

    url = 'http://search.11st.co.kr/SearchPrdAction.tmall?method=getTotalSearchSeller&isGnb=Y&prdType=&category=&cmd=&pageSize=&lCtgrNo=&mCtgrNo=&sCtgrNo=&dCtgrNo=&fromACK=recent&semanticFromGNB=&gnbTag=TO&schFrom=&schFrom=&ID=&ctgrNo=&srCtgrNo=&keyword=&adUrl=&adKwdTrcNo=&adPrdNo=&targetTab=T&kwd=' + url_item_name
    resp = requests.get(url)
    resp.raise_for_status()

    resp.encoding='euc-kr'
    plain_text = resp.text

    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, 'lxml')
    mytag = soup.find_all(True, {"class": ["sale_price", "list_info"]})
    #for link in soup.select('div.list_info p.info_tit a') :
    data = {}
    count = -1;
    for link in mytag:
        if(link.find('a')):
            count+=1
            href = link.find('a').get('href')
            product_name = link.find('a').string
            data[count] = str(href) + ", " + str(product_name)
        else:
            product_price = link.string
            if(product_price):
                data[count] = data[count] +", " + str(product_price)

    for value in data.values():
        print(value)
    resp.close()

    return data
```

and this is my views

```
def post_shop_list(request):
    posts = spider("product name")
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html',{'posts' : posts})
```

and this is my post_list.html

```
{% for key, value in posts.items %}
    <div>
        <td>{{key}}</td>
        <p>product name :{{value}}</p>
        <h1><a href=href> </a></h1>
        <p>{{ product_price|linebreaksbr}}</p>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Thank you .. !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i'd advise against doing these sort of things in templates. you end up having half of your view logic embedded in them.
i suggest doing something like this *in your view* or better yet *your crawler*:

```
products = []
for key, value in posts.items():
    product = value.split(',')
    # product = [href,name,price]
    product_entry = {
            'key' : key,
            'name' : product[1],
            'href' : product[0],
            'price' : product[2]
    }
    products.append(product_entry)
```

You end up with a nice array of dicts, hand it out to the template and in there you simply iterate over it and read the elements fields.

```
{% for item in products %}
    <td>{{ item.key }}</td>
    <p>product name :{{ item.name}}</p>
    <h1><a href={{ item.href }}> </a></h1>
    <p>{{ item.price }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Alternatively, create a custom template-tag as described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters)

Comment: Thank you for your kindness answer, I just try to this solution but, it displays first product data..

Answer (score 7):

Create custom [**`template filter`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-template-tags/#custom-template-tags-and-filters)

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='split')
def split(value, key):
  """
    Returns the value turned into a list.
  """
  return value.split(key)
```

In Django template you can use it like.

```
# assuming value = "url, product_name, product_price"
# and you have always these three comma separated items in sequence
{% for key, value in posts.items %}
   <tr>
      {% with value|split:"," as details %}
         {% for p in details %}
            <td>{{ p }}</td>
         {% endfor %}
      {% endwith %} 
   </tr>    
{% endfor %}
```

**UPDATE**

You have to also make entry of your tag file in TEMPLATE list in `libraries` keyword.

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            str(APPS_DIR.path('templates')),
        ],
        'OPTIONS': {

            'loaders': [
                ...
            ],

            'context_processors': [
                ...
            ],
            'libraries':{
               # make your file entry here.
               'filter_tags': 'app.templatetags.filter',
            }
        },
    },
]
```

and then load this tag to top of your html file where you want to use `split` filter

```
{% load filter_tags %}
```

Comment: I try to this solution but, it occurred error likes
django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Invalid filter: 'split'

I made a templatetags directory, created __init__.py, created filter.py and i put codes
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='split')
def split(value, key):
    return value.split(key)


register.filter('split',split)

Comment: check my update section, you have missed few things.